# All Pods becomes red and code won't compile

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods, ios-simulator

All my frameworks added through pods become red when i selector simulator, but they work fine when device is selected. [image]

This is when simulator is selected.[image]

This is one when i select device.
So, i'm unable to run the app on simulator.

Comment: Can we see your Podfile?

Comment: Yes, it's there.